# What is the name of Scar's brother?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-brotherhood, fullmetal-alchemist-2003

I was watching FMA Brotherhood, and I was wondering if any of the episodes in the original FMA Anime revealed Scar's brother's name. Now that I think about it, it really didn't really address it. Did they leave it out as it was not important? So far I haven't had any luck finding his name in any of the FMA or FMA Brotherhood episodes.

Does anyone know his name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because there is no known name for him. Scar and his brother also don't have a family name, as Scar himself never revealed his name:

> Scar's brother (real name unknown) [source](http://fma.wikia.com/wiki/Scar%27s_brother)

Answer (score 7):

Scar's brother's name is never revealed in the 2003 series, *Brotherhood*, or the manga. I remember reading somewhere that the creator had given names to both Scar and his brother, but they were never revealed in any interview or through official media.